# What the proper way of using "WHERE" clause when it needs to fetch data by approximate value of some field?

Tags: mysql, fetch, where-clause

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| 13.00 |
| 15.00 |
| 17.50 |
| 18.00 |
| 18.10 |
| 18.30 |
| 19.90 |
| 20.00 |
| 20.30 |
| 20.60 |
+-------+
```

`` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` = 19; ``

I want retrieve rows which contains `value` from 18.00 to 20.60 (plus or minus 2)

Number 19 I'm geting by POST.

Comment: It looks like you want to get the seven rows with values "closest" to 19. The trick there is to compute the difference between 19 and the value column, take the absolute value, and then sort by that difference. See my answer.  *Answer updated based on comment left on answer... to get a range of values... see my edited answer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `between`

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE value between $posted_value - 2 and $posted_value + 2
```

Comment: number 19 I'm geting by POST. I dont know anything about 18.0 and 20.6 numbers

Comment: Then see my query above. But why `20.6`?

Comment: 20.6 just for example. I need `value` plus or minus 2

Comment: @ILMIR: that information should probably be provided in your question, rather than as a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

If you want a range of +2 or -2, the most efficient way to do that would be:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM `table` t
 WHERE t.value >= 19 - 2.0
   AND t.value <= 19 + 2.0
 ORDER BY t.value
```

### original

To get just the value column from the seven rows with values "closest" to 19, calculate the difference between 19 and the value in the `value` column, take the absolute value of the difference, and then sort by that. Then limit the number of rows returned:

```
SELECT s.value
  FROM (
         SELECT s.value
           FROM `table` s
          ORDER BY ABS(19.0-s.value)
          LIMIT 7
       ) s
 ORDER BY s.value
```

To get the entire row, for the rows with the values "closest" to 19, you could do the same query, but also retrieve a unique identifier from the row, and then perform a join to the original table, for example:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM (
         SELECT r.id
              , r.value
              , ABS(19.0-r.value) AS `absdiff`
           FROM `table` r
          ORDER BY ABS(19.0-r.value)
          LIMIT 7
       ) s
  JOIN `table` t
    ON t.id = s.id
```

Comment: `"a BETWEEN b AND c"` is a shorthand equivalent to `"a >= b AND a <= c"`. There's no difference in the execution plan or performance of either.